# J2ME bluetooth service not discoverable by PC

Tags: java-me, bluetooth

I have a J2Me app that advertises a service. This service can be detected by other phones (that run the j2me client for this service) but cannot be detected by a PC. What could be the problem? Or how can I have the PC detect such a service using the PCs inbuilt bluetooth adaptor (i.e. am assuming it should be listed along with the services such as obex, remote control etc when I perform a scan)

**Update**

I am scanning for all services advertised by the phone. Obex was just an example. What I've done is defined a service (lets call it) `My Stuff`. Should I be able to see `My Stuff` along with all the other services provided by the phone (i.e. obex, remote control etc). Or is there something that needs to be added so that PCs as well as phones can see this service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what the scanner on your PC is looking for.  If it's looking for just OBEX, you need to advertise your service as OBEX (UUID 0x1105 IIRC), otherwise it won't come up.

Try writing your own bluetooth scanner for your PC (can be done in Java using, for example, the [BlueCove](http://bluecove.org/) JSR82 implementation.

**Update**

Your PC probably *can* "see" the service, however I bet your device scanning software is only showing stuff that it actually knows how to talk to.  It figures out whether it can talk to a service by matching the UUIDs it provides, against the known UUIDs of protocols it understands (see list [here](http://www.avetana-gmbh.de/avetana-gmbh/produkte/doc/javax/bluetooth/UUID.html) for example).

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, I scanned using the UUID instead of the address and it worked!